# iTunesConnect, Sales and Trends, Units

Tags: app-store-connect

Are units in iTunesConnect Sales and Trends report aggregated over all time? For example, if I show 100 units one week and 150 units the next week, do I have 250 downloads for all time or just 150 for all time? If it's the latter, what explains a decrease in units? Uninstalls?

Thanks!

Comment: just look at the bar chart version if it. it'll even show you how many by day

Comment: This means 250 for all time. Uninstalls are not shown/taken into account, the numbers are just installs.